# Resolve real path in NSString, without ".." (previous directory references)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, path, nsstring

OK, let me explain...

I have an `NSString` and a path stored in it, like this (as weird as it may look) :

> /A/B/C/../D/../E/F

which is practically the same as :

> /A/B/E/F

What I want is to convert the first path format (with the `..`s in it) the the second format.

Is there any built-in Cocoa function for something like that?

Any ideas?

Comment: @PiyushPatel This has nothing to do with the original purpose of this post...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found it! :-)

```
-(NSString *)stringByStandardizingPath;
```

> Returns a new string made by removing extraneous path components from
>   the receiver.

[NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByStandardizingPath).

Comment: Also note : *In relative paths, because symbolic links can’t be resolved, references to the parent directory are left in place.*

Comment: @Vince Thanks Vince; I noticed that part. However, it doesn't really matter since I'll be dealing only with absolute paths... ;-)